# How to resolve Selenium error - " by.css(...).getText is not a function"?

Tags: function, selenium, protractor, automated-tests

I am trying to compare text present in table using Selenium, but my automated tests fails saying `by.css(...).getText is not a function`. How can I resolve this error?

```
expect(by.css('table tr:nth-of-type(9) [colspan]').getText()).toEqual("This is test data.");
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just missed `element` function.

It should be:

```
expect(element(by.css('table tr:nth-of-type(9) [colspan]')).getText()).toEqual("This is test data.");
```

or:

```
expect($('table tr:nth-of-type(9) [colspan]').getText()).toEqual("This is test data.");
```